# can I use another custom environment variable name instead of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: c#, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-client

in order to enable multiple credentials to my application - I want to use custom environment variable for each.

how can I set it explicitly?

in [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#api-keys) I see only this default option.

Edit:

the libraries I'm using are Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 and Google.Apis.Dataflow.v1b3

I succeeded by using this

```
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"c:\certs\sa.json");
var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credentials);
```

Comment: Which library are you using? You don't *need* to use environment variables at all - you can load the credentials explicitly and specify them when constructing the client... but I'll need to know the library in order to give sample code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a API-specific topic and should be directed to the API support team.

Comment: @gunr2171: It's not particularly API-specific - there are basically two kinds of .NET libraries for Google APIs, and once we know which type it is, it will be easy to provide an example. SO is full of library-specific questions. Even if it were for just one library, it's fine to ask questions specific to one library on SO...

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my question, and added the libraries. I saw now that the constructor can get credentials. I'll look into it. BTW, I can't found examples in c# for most of the usages of those libraries, am I missed something, or it not exists?

Comment: @arielorvits: I don't know about Dataflow, but there are various examples of using the Storage library in the Storage documentation, e.g. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the default credential creation, only this environment variable is possible

[(example in python)](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default)

```
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
```

Now, think at the value that you put in the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var. It's simply a path to a service account key file. So, [you can do that, which is equivalent to the previous command](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#module-google.oauth2.service_account)

```
import google.auth

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'))
```

And thus, you can use the env var name that you want and create an explicit credential by passing the path to the correct file!

Example in C#:

```
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"c:\certs\trigger-sa.json");
var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credentials);
```